# cakephp model class not found error while upgrading

Tags: php, cakephp, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my CakePHP application from `1.3.6` to `2.2.4`

I did all the upgrade steps based on official CakePHP upgrade documentation.

But i am struggling with this error:

> Class 'Content' not found in
>   C:\wamp\www\cakephp-2.2.4\app\Controller\Component\OrderBaseComponent.php
>   on line 20
>
> Argument 1 passed to Component::__construct() must be an instance of
>   ComponentCollection, none given, called in
>   C:\wamp\www\cakephp-2.2.4\app\Controller\Component\OrderBaseComponent.php
>   on line 17 and defined [CORE\Cake\Controller\Component.php, line 77]

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html

Comment: Can you show some code? How do you load the Content class?

Answer (score 0):

For the first error make sure you **always** App::uses() every single class you use in your code.
So your Content (whatever class it is) must also be included before you can actually use it.

Only if it is a model you can just use `ClassRegistry::init()`, otherwise put sth like
`App::uses('Content', '[TYPE]');` at the top of the file.

This second error is pretty self-explanatory!
Look into the outlined "CORE\Cake\Controller\Component.php" file and make sure your function does have the exact same arguments in your custom component:

```
public function __construct(ComponentCollection $collection, $settings = array()) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

We don't have any relevant source code but generally you might add this at the top or your component file:

**First:**

```
 App::uses('Content', 'Model');
```

And you might have to add something like in your init or construct method:

```
$this->Content = ClassRegistry::init('Content');
```

That should solve the first issue or give a clear explanation about what goes wrong. Actually this code was likely already not correctly independent functional.

I suspect it depends on the Model to be loaded already in another piece of code that's why it worked likely. A component should work not dependent on other pieces of code so adding the App::uses, App::import etc statements makes the code work always. For example when you re-use it in your other projects.

**Second:**

The second issue comes really with migration issues. Check that the model extends the Component class first.

Then make sure that if you implement a custom method __construct() but also init() for example that you check whether you should add a call to the parent. For example this applies to beforeFilter controller method.

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
}
```

Documentation and code example from: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#the-app-controller

Relevant piece of documentation: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html#components